# Как привести к общему делителю уравнение в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, library, sympy, уравнения

Всем привет!

У меня есть задание , составить программу для решения уравнения на python.
Как можно привести к общему делителю ? Уже несколько дней пытаюсь , никак не получается . Пытался через библиотеку SymPy сделать через функцию together, но он не решает так как надо . Если есть простое число , то он его не умножает на общий делитель .Посоветуйте пожалуйста библиотеку или код.

```
y0,y1,y2,y3,y4 = symbols("y0"), symbols("y1"), symbols("y2"), symbols("y3") ,symbols("y4")

y_list = [y0, y1 , y2 , y3 , y4]

h = 0.1

x0 = 1.2
xn = 1.5


x_list = [round(x0 + i*0.1 , 6) for i in range(4)]

print(x_list)

x = symbols("x")



f = 0.8

for i in range(1,len(x_list)):
    yi_form = ((y_list[i+1] - 2 * y_list[i] + y_list[i-1])/h**2) - (x_list[i] * (y_list[i+1] - y_list[i-1])/2*h) + (2 * x_list[i] * y_list[i]) - f
    print(yi_form)
```

[image: Мне надо из такого уравнения получить]

[image: такое уравнение]

Comment: Надо из первого , получить второе уравнение

Comment: `.../2*h` Это неправильная запись